# picturebox array does not output images?

Tags: vb.net

I have a picture box array set up

```
Dim i = 7
    Dim s As PictureBox() = New PictureBox(0) {}
    s(0) = New PictureBox()

    s(0).Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Pic Folder\pic.png")
            s(0).Location = New Point(10, 10)
            s(0).Size = New Size(50, 50)
```

however, no image shows up at all. before, when i had declared a new picturebox and put the specifications as the new picturebox (say, foo.Image as opposed to s(0)) it worked fine

Comment: Your code creates a zero-sized array, so setting element `0` will fail (because element `0` is the first element). Your code is probably crashing but the exception is being silently caught somewhere. Have you tried using a step-through debugger?

Comment: i haven't gone through the debugger yet, butwould giving the array a size fix the problem?

Comment: You probably should use a `List<PictureBox>` instead. But what is your actual goal? If you just want to load multiple images into a form then you don't need to do any of this - you can create an add new `PictureBox` instances directly to the `Form.Controls` collection.

Comment: it's part of a bigger project- the idea is when you type something out, a symbol comes out, so i have to make one for each symbol (10-20) so it'd get really time wasting later

Comment: doesn't seem like you add it to the container `Me.Controls.Add(s(0))`.

Comment: ah that was it. thanks- everything working fine now

Comment: "i haven't gone through the debugger yet". Then you shouldn't have posted a question here yet either. If you haven't debugged your code then you haven't tried to diagnose the issue yourself and if you haven't tried then you shouldn't be asking others to do it for you.

Comment: @Dai : Infact, `New PictureBox(0) {}` is equal to `New PictureBox(0 To 0) {}` which in VB.NET will declare one element. An array of zero size would be `New PictureBox(-1) {}`. See [**this MSDN documentation article**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) for more info.